# How to fetch data from World Bank API (status is 200 But executing error block in jquery/ajax)

Tags: jquery, json, jsonp

I have below code to fetch the data which is in json format (http://api.worldbank.org/countries/all/indicators/PALM_OIL?date=2000M01:2020M12&per_page=1000&format=json)

Actually, I have specified `dataType: jsonp`, So the request is happening with status 200 and the data is coming in response but the `success` handler is not invoked, Its invoking `error` block.

Code is below

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
   $.ajax({
      contentType: "application/json",
         dataType: 'jsonp',
         crossDomain: true,
         url: "http://api.worldbank.org/countries/all/indicators/PALM_OIL?date=2000M01:2020M12&per_page=1000&format=json",
         success: function() { console.log("success"); },
         error: function() { console.log("error"); }
     });


 });
</script>
```

Comment: why are you using jsonp?

Comment: OKay, jsonp is not supported in world bank API, I solved it by using file_get_contents()

Answer (score 0):

Using php function `file_get_contents` we can achieve this.